# Querying Cloud Datastore - Returning all submissions from currently logged in user

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to retrieve all entities that a user has submitted and have tried to do this by using the user's email address as the filter, but I receive this error when querying the datastore:

`ValueError: Name 'test@example.com' cannot contain period characters`

Query:

```
email = users.get_current_user().email()

q = WorkRequest.query().filter(email)
results = q.fetch(10)
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not structured the query properly.  Try this:

```
mail = users.get_current_user().email()

q = WorkRequest.query(WorkRequest.email == mail)
results = q.fetch(10)
```